# Reducing flicker in Kindle/e-ink web content?

Tags: kindle

Do guidelines exist for writing web applications that will be viewed on the Kindle Paperwhite or other e-ink based devices?  I'm especially looking for techniques to reduce flicker when updating images.

Comment: do you have any new information? Are they some tutorials?

Comment: haven't heard a thing!  vote the question up, maybe it will get some more attention...